# Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_3: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Tags: keras

what I can do this problem?

train_points.shape=(4096,3)
train_labels.shape=(4096,2)

Hello there. I have 3D roof models in my hand and I converted these models to point cloud data. each model has 2048 points (for x, y and z coordinates). that is (2048.3). and I also created a tag matrix. (2048.1). It gives me this error when I use conv1d. I can't understand where is the problem?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import keras
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import trimesh
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore') #filter warnings

mesh=trimesh.load("m1.stl")
mesh.show()
point1 = mesh.sample(2048) #modelin üstündeki nokta sayısı

mesh=trimesh.load("m2.stl")
mesh.show()
point2 = mesh.sample(2048) #modelin üstündeki nokta sayısı



train_points=np.concatenate((point1,point2),axis=0)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(222, projection="3d")
ax.scatter(point1[:, 0], point1[:, 1], point1[:, 2])
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.show()


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(222, projection="3d")
ax.scatter(point2[:, 0], point2[:, 1], point2[:, 2])
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.show()


labels=np.zeros((4096),dtype='int') #4096=örnek sayısı
labels[0:2048]=0
labels[2048:4096]=1

from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical # convert to one-hot-encoding
train_labels= to_categorical(labels,2) #2=örnek sınıf sayısı
np.save('etiket_matrisi.npy',train_labels)


from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPool1D

#input_shape = keras.Input(shape=(4096, 3))
input_shape=(2,2048,3)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(filters=8,kernel_size=3,input_shape=input_shape,padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Conv1D(filters=8,kernel_size=3,input_shape=input_shape,padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Dense(8))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))


#fully connected
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax")) #çıktı katmanı(2 modelim var)

#Compile Model
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary


#fit the model

history=model.fit(train_points, train_labels, epochs=500, batch_size=250, verbose=1)
```

Comment: Hi merve and welcome. I think your question needs more details about what you're trying to achieve or what is that code for, also, you may want to format the code parts. This way you add more clarity and helps reviewers to come up with a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Hello there. I have 3D roof models in my hand and I converted these models to point cloud data. each model has 2048 points (for x, y and z coordinates). that is (2048.3). and I also created a tag matrix. (2048.1). It gives me this error when I use conv1d. I can't understand where is the problem?

Comment: Hey Merve, thanks for replying back, please edit your question with the additional info. Thanks